# O que existe depois do "php artisan serve" no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou em duvida do que aconteceu exatamente. Encotrei esse erro no sistema em que estou desenvolvendo. Quando eu inicializo o meu servidor no Laravel aparece um suposto "=" depois de usar o **`php artisan serve`**. Esse mesmo "=" aparece sempre no canto superior esquerdo em qualquer página feita nas *views*. O exemplo seguinte mostra o que aparece.

```
=Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

Esperado aparecer o seguinte resultado:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

Tentei procurar algo na *view* principal. Não encontrei nada incomum. Acredito que seja algo envolvendo o comando ***php artisan serve***. Gostaria de saber exatamente como esse comando funciona e em quais arquivos da minha aplicação **Laravel** eu posso estar consultando para tentar encontrar esse erro. Ou se esse erro não tem nenhuma relação com o comando em si.

> Obs: Acredito que o apache2 esteja envolvido também, mas não sei a
>   procedência disso.

Comment: Isso está parecendo um caractere que você digitou errado em algum arquivo e não percebeu. Se utilizar Git veja no histórico de edições o que foi alterado.

Comment: Procure nas suas `Views` você digitou isso não tem nada a ver com o `artisan`, resumindo, o problema é local e aparente difícil reprodução

Comment: Comece um projeto do zero e veja se isso também ocorre. Já tive um [problema parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915076/strange-characters-in-php-cli-output) que era relacionado com a codificação de um arquivo em UFT-8 com BOM (provavelmente não é o seu caso)

Comment: Não deve ser relacionado ao apache pq o artisan serve usa o servidor embutido do php (veja o arquivo [ServeCommand.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php))

Comment: Deixe o artisan serv de lado. Use o apache que é mais rapido e eficiente. Aponte o rootdir para /public/ e seja feliz.

Comment: Consegui arrumar, procurei por =<?php e estava na view principal do sistema.

Comment: @Risk não soube dessa possibilidade, obrigado pela a dica. Mas não entendi se procede isso utilizando Laravel

Comment: Você tem o APACHE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É muito provável que você tenha digitado o caractere '=' em algum arquivo que é incluído em todo o ciclo de vida do framework e que este caractere esteja antes de uma tag `<?php`.

Faça uma busca nos arquivos do projeto por uma string como `=<?php`.

Comment: funcionou certinho, agradeço pela a ajuda. Era uma situação minima, procurei por essa string e acabou dando certo. Muito obrigado